# UIAlertView not displaying the keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have  UIAlertView which is being displayed upon the load of a view.

```
 av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"New Password" message:@"please enter a new passward" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"done", nil];

av.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;
[av becomeFirstResponder];   


[av show];
```

However the keyboard is not being display on the iPad or the simulator?

I have also tried

I just tried

```
[av becomeFirstResponder];
```

and also

```
 UITextField *text = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];

[text becomeFirstResponder];
```

I just tried this piece of code and it logs that the textField is the first responder but still no keyboard.

```
if([[av textFieldAtIndex:0] isFirstResponder] == YES){
    NSLog(@"av is the first responder.");
}
```

Comment: I'm using iOS 5 thats why its such a weird bug. Ive used alertView before and never had a problem with it.

Comment: @geminiCoder check this link it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346023/resignfirstresponder-doesnt-dismiss-the-keyboard-iphone

Comment: See this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563108/uialertviews-textfield-does-not-show-keyboard-in-ios8

Answer (score 3):

Making the alert into the first responder won't help. You need to make te text box inside the alert view into the first responder.

**Edit:**

You may need to call `reloadInputViews` (with or without the s, don't remember). Also double check that you're not changing the input views anywhere that might be breaking them.

**Edit 2:**

You might want to move the alert from viewDidLoad into viewDidAppear. I've seen problems with UI elements being updated/presented too early. This is one of those cases, I think.

Comment: Edit 2 helped me. My parent view was animated and it loaded before it actually appeared, so that was causing an inconsistency in the keyboard appearing. ViewDidAppear fixed this.

Comment: I was showing my alertView before dismissal of a modal viewController was complete. Moved [alertView show] to the completion block; Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

To use

```
  av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"New Password" message:@"please enter a new passward" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"done", nil];
 av.tag=1;
 av.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;

  [av show];
```

and use this method.

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertViews clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
 { 
  if (alertViews.tag==1)
 {
    [textfieldname becomeFirstResponder];
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this method and still no keyboard. really weird!!

Answer (score 1):

this works

```
 self.alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Login" message:@"Please enter you mobile number" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    self.alertView.alertViewStyle=UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
        [alertView show];
```

but not this

```
UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
[alertView initWithTitle:...]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"New Password" message:@"please enter a new passward" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"done", nil];

UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 45, 260, 25)];

CGAffineTransform Transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 60);

[tf setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[av setTransform:Transform];

[av addSubview:tf];

[av show];
```

This works but you should be able to do this in IOS 5 using UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but my solution looks like it might not apply to original poster...

I had this code :

```
UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
[alert initWithTitle:...]
```

When run, no keyboard appeared.

I changed it to this, and keyboard now appears:

```
UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:...];
```

Doing the init after alert was created seem to leave internal state of object as "this object doesn't need a keyboard!"