# UIAlertView's textfield does not show keyboard in iOS8

Tags: ios

```
@implementation
UIAlertView *query;
@end

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
query = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"New", @"")
                      message:nil
                      delegate:self
                      cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil)
                      otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @""), nil];
query.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField *textField = [_query textFieldAtIndex:0];
textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"Title", @"placeholder text where user enters name for new playlist");
textField.delegate = self;
[_query show];
}
```

After `UIAlertView` is shown, keyboard is shown too and `UITextfield` is focus (It just works on pre iOS7, but does not work in iOS8). I have tried `[textfield becomeFirstResponder]`, but it does not worked. I create new project and use cove above, it works.

My problem: Keyboard does not shown with `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput` style.

I don't know why? Can anybody helps me? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This ugly hack worked for me, after calling show:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // HACKHACK: This is to make the keyboard appear in iOS8
    UITextRange* textRange = self.textField.selectedTextRange;
    [self.textField selectAll:self];
    [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;
    self.textField.selectedTextRange = textRange;
});
```

Ran into the same problem, and spent hours fiddling with UIAlertController, which is the "right" solution, but unfortunately has several issues elsewhere (e.g. it breaks when presenting from a popover), and won't work with iOS7.

This is definitely a bug in iOS8. I hope Apple fixes this soon. It unfortunately breaks even with older binaries compiled for iOS7.

Comment: Thank you for your time. With GM xCode release version, at the first time UIAlertView is shown but keyboard does not shown. The second times and later, it always show keyboard. I think this is a bug of Apple. I will try like your suggestion. Once again, thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a slight improvement to Chen Lim's hack/fix, to be placed in the UIAlertViewDelegate:

```
- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    if (isIOS8) {
        // hack alert: fix bug in iOS 8 that prevents text field from appearing
        UITextRange *textRange = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] selectedTextRange];
        [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] selectAll:nil];
        [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] setSelectedTextRange:textRange];
    }
}
```

(You'll have to implement an isIOS8 method, property, or iVar.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time to answer my question.

Comment: Just doing the [tf selectAll:nil] in this method seems to do the trick.  Works for both 7.1 and 8.1.

Comment: It breaks `UITextView` sized by calling keyboard show notifications for the second time without hiding.

Comment: Also UIAlertView is jumping and blinking. So, the solution can't be used.

Comment: Is this hack still relevant for iOS 8.2?

Answer (score 3):

This helps me to fix all related issues:

```
[MyUITextView endEditing:YES];
```

Put it before showing `UIAlertView`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this was happening because the `UIViewController` that was presenting the `UIAlertView` had implemented `canBecomeFirstResponder` with a YES result since I wanted to listen for 'shake' events.

Once I added the following implementation of the `UIAlertViewDelegate` method the keyboard was presented as expected:

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}
```

So this may not solve all of the problems with this so-called 'deprecated' class but it is something to check if your controller is enabling first-responder behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that a text field already had first responder status, so the keyboard was already visible when the alert code was invoked. Dismissing this field fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing this on a device, or just in the sim?

There appears to be an issue with the iOS8 sim where it detects a physical keyboard, and doesn't show the software keyboard.  Could possibly be intentional, as you technically are using a physical keyboard...it's just not the ideal behavior for sim testing.

Try command K to toggle the software keyboard in the sim if that's your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I came cross with the same situation,and how I solved this bug is trying to resign current responder before showing the `alertView`.And `UITextField`'s keyboard is popping up as expected.

```
UITextField *textField = ...; // Suppose textField is currently being edited.
[textField resignFirstResponder]; // before showing,resign first.

[_query show];
```

Answer (score -2):

[The first page of the UIAlertView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) states:

> **Subclassing Notes** 
>   The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this
>   class is private and must not be modified.
>
> For more information about appearance and behavior configuration, see
>   “Alert Views”.

In other words, you shouldn't be messing around with the contents of UIAlertView window.  The fact it actually works in earlier OS versions than iOS 8 is just a bonus.  It's deprecated as of iOS 8.

What you'll want to do in iOS 8 is make use of the [brand new UIAlertController class](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertController/addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:), which does allow editable text fields.

Comment: How is this subclassing? It is a plain old technique of accessing the `UIAlertView`'s `textField(s)`, unless i'm missing something.

Comment: @Michael Dautermann: Thanks for your answer. My problem is the keyboard does not automatically shown when I show UIAlertView with style "UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput"? I remove code which access alertview's textfield, but it does not show keyboard. Do you have any suggestion for me?

Comment: it's because the views within UIAlertView are meant to be private and read-only.  The fact that apps get away with messing around with it mean that things can (and in the O.P.'s case they ***do***) break between major iOS releases.

Comment: Once again, thank you for your answer. I use UIAlertController in iOS8 and it works well.:D

Comment: "you shouldn't be messing around": apple's ios should not have bugs then.