# ios8 UIAlertView becomeFirstResponder for Password UITextField not working

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uialertview

This was working OK in iOS7. After upgrading to iOS8 it is strangely not working.

So, if the user has already logged in before, the username is saved and a password is required. Quite simply, I was just inputting the username in the 0 index `UITextField` and setting the cursor at the 1 index `UITextField` of the `UIAlertView`.

Before I just had to set the `becomeFirstResponder` to the number 1 index `UITextField` in the `UIAlertView`. The strange thing is that I can actually set text into the number 1 index `UITextField`. So I know I'm accessing the `UITextField` correctly still.

Pretty straightforward code.

Here's my code...

```
- (IBAction)actionTesting:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Login" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
    alert.tag = 999;

    UITextField *txtUserName = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    UITextField *txtPassword = [alert textFieldAtIndex:1];

    txtUserName.text = @"";
    txtPassword.text = @"";

    [alert textFieldAtIndex:1].delegate = self;
    [alert show];
}

-(void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView{
    UITextField *txtUserName = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    UITextField *txtPassword = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1];
    txtUserName.text = @"username";
    txtPassword.text = @"password";
    [txtPassword becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

It looks like we have a new `UIAlertController` available. I was just hoping to get this working so I didn't have to do any changes to my original code for now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIAlertView's textfield does not show keyboard in iOS8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563108/uialertviews-textfield-does-not-show-keyboard-in-ios8)

Comment: Are you running this code on a simulator?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Apple corrected this issue. I just noticed the other day that the functionality was working

Comment: _uialertview_ is now **deprecated** use _uialertcontroller_