# Show UIAlertView and keyboard simultaneously

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, uialertview

It looks like iOS 8 has a bug where alerts with text input do not show the keyboard. I have tried [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25919727/707381).

The problem with the hack is that first the alert appears, and only afterwards does the keyboard appear. This causes the alert to "jump up" to make space for the keyboard.

How can I have a `UIAlertView` with text input, where the keyboard appears immediately?

(Note: For an example of what I want, go to Voice Memos, record a new memo, save, and you'll be prompted to enter a name with a `UIAlertView` with text input. There, the keyboard appears at the same time as the `UIAlertView`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure this will perfectly solve the problem of keyboard and alertView appearing simultaneously. But I would recommend you to use the newer api. I am posting this as an answer as its difficult to put code into comments.

For some reasons `UIAlertView` has been deprecated in iOS 8. Instead of using the `UIAlertView` you should use the `UIAlertController` with style `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert`. Present it and then open keyboard.

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:yourTitle message:yourMessage preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Since the alert now is shown as `UIViewController` the keyboard won't shift the alert box upside.

Comment: This makes no attempt to answer the question. Update the answer so it actually explains how to make the keyboard appear at the same time as the alert.

Comment: I am just suggesting OP to use a newer api.

Comment: @VinayJain But an answer needs to answer the question. If you just want to make an unrelated suggestion, post it as a comment.

Comment: @rmaddy: It's totally related. I'm using iOS8, and I want a working alert with text input.

Comment: @Randomblue I'm confused. You asked a specific question. How to show the keyboard the same time as showing a `UIAlertView`. This answer doesn't tell you how to do that at all. All it does is suggest the newer API. While the suggestion is useful, it doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @VinayJain Yes and it still doesn't answer the question. Where's the code in your answer that results in the keyboard appearing at the same time as the alert?

Answer (score 0):

//ctrl+k to appear keyboard and ios8 keyboard appearing simultaneously issue would solve by this...

```
UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"Registration Successfully" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction * ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){

                            // [self.view endEditing:YES];
                            // [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

                         }];
[alert addAction:ok];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```